# How to make different pages of a QStackedWidget of different sizes?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qstackedwidget

I have a `QStackWidget` with 2 pages. One page contains just 2 `QLineEdit` widget and another page contains a large `QTextEdit`. Does anyone know how to make one page larger than another so that the window still fits tightly for each page? In the Qt Designer, the `QStackWidget` has to take the larger size in order to first the `QTextEdit`, but then the page with the `QLineEdit` widgets would be way too big.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the size policy of the page that is displayed to `QSizePolicy.Preferred` and the other ones to `QSizePolicy.Ignored`. After that call `adjustSize` to update the sizes. For example when you set the current index to show `page1` :

```
page1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
page2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)

stackedWidget.adjustSize()
adjustSize()
```

And when the other page is shown, set the size policies the other way.

Comment: But then, how does the stacked widget take the size of the smaller or larger page? If I use `QWidget` for the pages, `sizehint()` returns -1 -1

Comment: try `resize(minimumSizeHint());`. This would shrink it to minimum size.

Comment: Right. If I print `page1.minimumSizeHint()` (likewise for `page2`), I get `QSize(-1, -1)`. Should the pages be of class `QWidget`?

Comment: It can be any widget. Just should be derived from `QWidget`.